# I use seek("cur",-1) to traverse a txt file from the end to begin,but when it face a new line,there will be two "\n" in continuous postion,why?

Tags: lua

I test the "\n" with "#",the length equial 1 and when i read "\n" with f:read(1),it just execute once.This is strange situation.
this is code:

```
function exercise7_5(inputfile,cnt)
  cnt=cnt or 1
  local inputF=io.open(inputfile,"r")
  local spcnt,seeknow=0,0
  seeknow = inputF:seek("end")
  repeat
    seeknow = inputF:seek("cur",-1)
    local linecheck=inputF:read(1)
    seeknow=inputF:seek("cur",-1)
    print("seeknow"..seeknow)
    if linecheck=="\n" then
      spcnt=spcnt+1
      seeknow = inputF:seek("cur",-1)
      print("seeknow huan"..seeknow)
    end
  until spcnt==cnt or seeknow==0 
  if seeknow~=0 then
    inputF:seek("cur",2)
  end
  local ansstr=inputF:read("a")
  inputF:close()
  return ansstr
end
print(exercise7_5("fnamea.txt",2))
```

Comment: I show the two "\n" with string.byte,their value all equil c10,so i think it not match with "\r\n"

Comment: Try open the file in binary mode `io.open(inputfile,"rb")`

Comment: It solves the problem.